# java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE002 method name is invalid

Tags: java, websphere, classformaterror

I've deployed an EAR in IBM WebSphere and when I hit the local url, I get the below error:

> java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE002 method name is invalid; class=com/hcsc/premier/provider/web/database/message/ErrorWarningMessageNumber, offset=0

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: [A good exception is an excellent search keyword](https://www.google.com/search?q=java.lang.ClassFormatError%3A+JVMCFRE002+method+name+is+invalid).

Answer (score 0):

This provides a discussion:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV12263

Early JVM's have a more restrictive specification for valid class and method names.

The recommended fix is to update the JVM to a higher level.  According to the linked discussion, these JVM's handle the newer class and method name specification:

6.0.0 SR10
6.0.1 SR1
7.0.0 SR1

If the JVM cannot be changed, the alternative would be to modify the problem class to remove special characters from class and method names.

Thx!
Tom Bitonti